# web2py A() link handling with multiple targets

Tags: ajax, web2py

I need to update multiple targets when a link is clicked.
This example builds a list of links.
When the link is clicked, the callback needs to populate two different parts of the .html file.

The actual application uses bokeh for plotting.
The user will click on a link,  the 'linkDetails1' and 'linkDetails2' will hold the script and div return from calls to bokeh.component()
The user will click on a link, and the script, div returned from bokeh's component() function will populate the 'linkDetails'.

Obviously this naive approach does not work.
How can I make a list of links that when clicked on will populate two separate places in the .html file?

```
################################
#views/default/test.html:

{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=linkDetails1}}
{{=linkDetails2}}
{{=links}}

################################
# controllers/default.py:
def test():
    """
    example action using the internationalization operator T and flash
    rendered by views/default/index.html or views/generic.html

    if you need a simple wiki simply replace the two lines below with:
    return auth.wiki()
    """
    d = dict()
    links = []
    for ii in range(5):
      link = A("click on link %d"%ii, callback=URL('linkHandler/%d'%ii), )
      links.append(["Item %d"%ii, link])
    table = TABLE()
    table.append([TR(*rows) for rows in links])
    d["links"] = table
    d["linkDetails1"] = "linkDetails1" 
    d["linkDetails2"] = "linkDetails2" 
    return d

def linkHandler():
    import os
    d = dict()
    # request.url will be linked/N
    ii = int(os.path.split(request.url)[1])

    # want to put some information into linkDetails, some into linkDiv
    # this does not work:
    d = dict()
    d["linkDetails1"] = "linkHandler %d"%ii 
    d["linkDetails2"] = "linkHandler %d"%ii 
    return d
```

Comment: If you add a "target" argument to the `A()` helper, the HTML returned by the Ajax call will be inserted in the HTML element whose ID matches "target". If you additionally want to put some content in another element, you can write some Javascript code to handle that and return the Javascript via `response.js`. However, it is not clear what you want to put where, as you have not shown your view code nor explained what is supposed to happen with the two linkDetails keys in the returned dict. It would help if you could shown the view code and be more explicit about the output you desire.

Comment: Anthony, the view code is at the top of the code listing. A click on the A() link is to update the information in the two fields linkDetails1 and linkDetails2. This is a stripped-down test program . In the real app the links will display different bokeh plots. bokeh's plotting code returns a div with a random id and a script that references that id. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Yes, but in the view, there is no linkDiv, and the two linkDetails items are just text nodes, so it is difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. Also, you haven't shown the view for linkHandler. To create the Bokeh plots, do you need to return HTML or JS code? What content goes in linkDiv (and what/where is linkDiv)?

Comment: Sorry, the comment in linkHandler is wrong.

Comment: I want the two text nodes to be replaced with text that are a script and a div respectively. `code` def linkHandler():
    import os
    d = dict()
    d["linkDetails1"] = "<script></script>"
    d["linkDetails2"] = "<div></div>"
    return d

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do here, but if you need to update e.g. 2 div elements in your page in response to a single click, there are a couple of ways to accomplish that.

The easiest, and arguably most web2py-ish way is to contain your targets in an outer div that's a target for the update.

Another alternative, which is very powerful is to use something like Taconite [1], which you can use to update multiple parts of the DOM in a single response.

[1] http://www.malsup.com/jquery/taconite/

Comment: I tried putting the targets in an outer div, and what I got was another copy of the entire page (menus, everything) in the div. Weird, must have done something wrong.

Comment: If you don't have a view for linkHandler, by default (only on localhost) it will use the generic.html view, which extends the full layout.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it doesn't look like you need the Ajax call to return content to two separate parts of the DOM. Instead, both elements returned (the script and the div elements) can simply be placed inside a single parent div.

```
# views/default/test.html:

{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<div id="link_details">
  {{=linkDetails1}}
  {{=linkDetails2}}
</div>
{{=links}}

# controllers/default.py
def test():
    ...
    for ii in range(5):
        link = A("click on link %d" % ii,
                 callback=URL('default', 'linkHandler', args=ii),
                 target="link_details")
    ...
```

If you provide a "target" argument to `A()`, the result of the Ajax call will go into the DOM element with that ID.

```
def linkHandler():
    ...
    content = CAT(SCRIPT(...), DIV(...))
    return content
```

In `linkHandler`, instead of returning a dictionary (which requires a view in order to generate HTML), you can simply return a web2py HTML helper, which will automatically be serialized to HTML and then inserted into the target div. The `CAT()` helper simply concatenates other elements (in this case, your script and associated div).